# tensorflow: save model and load model

Tags: python, tensorflow

Currently trying to make this [repo](https://github.com/SenticNet/conv-emotion/tree/master/ICON-end-to-end) works.

I'm trying to save the trained model in the local machine so can be applied later. I read in tensorflow's [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/save), seems pretty intuitive to save the model, by calling `tf.save_model.save(object)`. But I'm not sure how to apply.

Original code is here: [model.py](https://github.com/SenticNet/conv-emotion/blob/master/ICON-end-to-end/model.py)
Following is my changes:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class ICON(tf.Module): # make it a tensorflow modul

    def __init__(self, config, embeddingMatrix, session=None):

    def _build_inputs(self):

    def _build_vars(self):

    def _convolution(self, input_to_conv):

    def _inference(self):

    def batch_fit(self, queries, ownHistory, otherHistory, labels):

        feed_dict = {self._input_queries: queries, self._own_histories: ownHistory, self._other_histories: otherHistory,
                     self._labels: labels}
        loss, _ = self._sess.run([self.loss_op, self.train_op], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        return loss

    def predict(self, queries, ownHistory, otherHistory, ):

        feed_dict = {self._input_queries: queries, self._own_histories: ownHistory, self._other_histories: otherHistory}
        return self._sess.run(self.predict_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)

    def save(self): # attempt to save the model
        tf.saved_model.save(
            self, './output/model')
```

The code above produces ValueError as following:
`ValueError: Tensor("ICON/CNN/embedding_matrix:0", shape=(16832, 300), dtype=float32_ref) must be from the same graph as Tensor("saver_filename:0", shape=(), dtype=string).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the tf.train.Saver class for this

```
def save(self): # attempt to save the model
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(self._sess, './output/model')
```

You can then restore the model this way

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./output/model.meta')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./output'))
```

You might also find this [tutorial](https://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/) helpful in understanding this more.

Edit: if you want to use SavedModel

```
def save(self):
    inputs = {'input_queries': self._input_queries, 'own_histories': self._own_histories, 'other_histories': self._other_histories}
    outputs = {'output': self.predict_op}
    tf.saved_model.simple_save(self._sess, './output/model', inputs, outputs)
```

You can then use tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model to load and serve using the SavedModel

```
from tensorflow.contrib.predictor import from_saved_model
predictor = from_saved_model('./output/model')
predictions = predictor({'input_queries': input_queries, 'own_histories': own_histories, 'other_histories': other_histories})
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: but `tf.train.Saver()` is used to store variables, but what I want is to store the model